# Сохранение введённых в терминал команд WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

При закрытии проекта в WebStorm не сохраняется история введённых в терминал команд. То есть, при открытии проекта заново, я не могу проверить, какие команды вводил до этого. Знаю, что такая возможность присутствует. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно настроить.

Answer (score 2):

[Настройки терминала WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/terminal-emulator.html#configure-the-terminal-emulator) (англ.)

##### Решение для Bash и Cygwin:

Добавьте в `~/.bashrc`

```
# Avoid duplicates
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
# When the shell exits, append to the history file instead of overwriting it
shopt -s histappend

# After each command, append to the history file and reread it
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND$'\n'}history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

[Источник](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1292/439940)

[Решение для PowerShell](http://woshub.com/powershell-commands-history/) (англ.)

Comment: Это, как я понимаю, сработает для Linux, а для Windows не подскажете решение?

Comment: Уважаемый DiD, я, видимо, не совсем так выразился в вопросе, я имею ввиду тот терминал, который находится внутри программы WebStorm.

Comment: [Настройка терминала](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/terminal-emulator.html#configure-the-terminal-emulator). Предложенное в ответе решение работает в Bash и должно быть работает в Cygwin. На данный момент нет компьютера с Windows под рукой. В ZSH по идее история должна сохраняться по умолчанию. Для PowerShell инструкция на английском языке по ссылке в комментарии.